# Taylor series of $F(n) = 1/(n-1)^2 - 1/n^2$ around large n?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am lost on this Taylor series. The hint says to let $x = 1/n$ and expand around $x = 0$, but I can't make any progress.

I am also confused why this hint is helpful. Can't I just expand around large $n$? Then I can assume $1/n^2, 1/n^3, ...$ and the other higher order derivatives to be about $0$, hence the Taylor series expansion would be $0$. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
F(n) 
&= \dfrac1{(n-1)^2} - \dfrac1{n^2}\\
&= \dfrac1{n^2}\left(\dfrac1{(1-1/n)^2} -1\right)\\
&= \displaystyle\dfrac1{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{k+1}{n^{2k}} -1\right)\\
&= \displaystyle\dfrac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{k+1}{n^{2k}} \\
&= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{k+1}{n^{2k+2}} \\
&= \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{k}{n^{2k}} \\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Do you know why wolfram alpha ends the term with O(x^9)? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+x%5E2*(1%2F(1-x)%5E2-1)+at+x+%3D+0

Comment: Wolfy works in mysterious ways its wonders to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do it with $x=\frac 1n$
$$F(x)=\frac{(2-x) x^3}{(1-x)^2}$$  Now, use the binomial expansion for the denominator
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2 x+3 x^2+4 x^3+5 x^4+6 x^5+7 x^6+\cdots$$
$$F(x)=(2-x) x^3 \left( 1+2 x+3 x^2+4 x^3+5 x^4+6 x^5+7 x^6+\cdots\right)$$
$$F(x)=2 x^3+3 x^4+4 x^5+5 x^6+6 x^7+7 x^8+8 x^9+\cdots$$
$$F(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k x^{k+1 }$$
$$F(n)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac k {n^{k+1 }}$$

Comment: I see thanks, but wolfram alpha ends with O(x^9) as the ending term, which doesn't agree with anything

Comment: @Goldname. Just because the truncated to $O(x^9)$ that is to say that they consider the terms up to $x^8$. It is more interesting to have the infinie sum (just as marty cohen also did). Truncate whereever you wish.